# UIButton Selector method not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uibutton

I am creating a UIIimageView programtically than I create the UIView and in uiview I added two uibutton programtically but button selector method not working . I tried many thing but nothing happened . Here is my code

```
-(void) pagingFunc{
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screen);



    //ScrollView Size and Contents
    CGSize mxSize = CGSizeMake( [imgesArry count]*width , height-114);
    [scrlView setContentSize : mxSize];

     self.customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =YES;
    self.customView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, mxSize.width, mxSize.height);


    int incX = 0 ;

    for( int i = 0; i < [imgesArry count]; i++)
    {
        PFObject *imageObject = [imgesArry objectAtIndex:i];
        PFFile *file;
        if (height == 480) {
            file = [imageObject objectForKey:@"image4s"];
        }
        else{
            file = [imageObject objectForKey:@"image6s"];
        }

    NSString * imgFile = [file  url];
     UIImageView*  imagView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame : CGRectMake(incX,0,width ,height)];
        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [imagView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgFile] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UserUpdationImageCell.png"]];
        btnView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(incX, imagView.frame.size.height-60, width, 50)];
        btnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:0.8];
        UIButton *bckBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [bckBtn addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(aMethod)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [bckBtn setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        bckBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,0, 160.0, 40.0);


        UIButton *downloadBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [downloadBtn addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(aMethod)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [downloadBtn setTitle:@"Download" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        downloadBtn.frame = CGRectMake(160 ,0, 160.0, 40.0);
        [btnView addSubview:bckBtn];
        [btnView addSubview:downloadBtn];
        [self.customView addSubview:imagView];
        [self.customView addSubview:btnView];


        incX+= width;
    }
    [scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(width*selectedIndex, 0)];


}
```

Comment: I also face same problem, and this is because, UIButton gets lose its target by any reason.

use UIButton+Block category, this helped me.

here is the link  https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/2468899

Comment: set `btnView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;`

Comment: now try link @Mahesh

Comment: I tried it before but "user interaction enabled" not worked @Paulw11

Comment: And `self.customView` ? - User interaction needs to be enabled on all superviews

Comment: tried but nothing happened @Paulw11

Comment: How is `aMethod` declared?

Comment: Does scrlView contain `customView`?  Does it have userInteractionEnabled?

Comment: -(void) aMethod{
    NSLog(@"back");
}
Here is the selector method @Paulw11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114813/discussion-between-salmancs43-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 0):

May be you can set : `self.customView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;`

I write a simple demo you describe and it works:

```
// imagView -> view1 -> bckBtn
    UIImageView *imagView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    imagView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imagView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:imagView];

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [imagView addSubview:view1];

    UIButton *bckBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    bckBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
    bckBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [bckBtn addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [bckBtn setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [view1 addSubview:bckBtn];

-(void)aMethod{
    NSLog(@"button click");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well 1st thing, make sure you don't have any overlays over buttons. 
Also you might try using GestureRecognizers.

Here's a Swift snippet, I'm pretty sure it can be translated to obj-c

```
let xButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 40))
xButton.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(aMethod)))
```